# Write int number to M95 EEPROM STM32 using HAL Lib

Tags: c

I'm currently using this Library to write Strings to EEPROM: https://github.com/firebull/STM32-EEPROM-SPI

This works great with uint8_t* Strings.

But I simply want to write Int Numbers to an adress.

```
                               NUMBER           ADDR            LENGH
I tried EEPROM_SPI_WriteBuffer(0x10, (uint16_t) 0x01, (uint16_t) 1);
```

But that dont work. I read just shit back.

Problem is, i think, that i dont have a pointer at 0x10. But how to do with an integer?

Comment: you need to ask that library author.

Comment: If there is no valid data at address 0x10, then why do you pass that address. Your weird "example" doesn't correspond with the Github code: `EepromOperations EEPROM_SPI_WriteBuffer(uint8_t* pBuffer, uint16_t WriteAddr, uint16_t NumByteToWrite);`. Given that, your code doesn't make any sense and won't even compile with strict C standard settings.

Comment: Based on the API on github (`EepromOperations EEPROM_SPI_WriteBuffer(uint8_t* pBuffer, uint16_t WriteAddr, uint16_t NumByteToWrite`) the first operand should be a pointer to an address holding `0x10`, not just `0x10`

Comment: For example, `uint8_t write_val = 0x10; EEPROM_SPI_WriteBuffer(&write_val, 0x01, 1);`

Comment: Thanks. Works. 

Can you tell me the last possible Adress / last byte? I dont see it in the Datasheet: https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/389/m95128-dre-1156081.pdf